Strong Maximum Principle for $p$-harmonic functions.
I have been looking for a Strong Maximum Principle for $p$-harmonic functions, that is, functions that solve the $p$-Laplace equation. I have not found any sources for that. I found this paper '$p$-Harmonic Functions On Metric Space' of Zohra Farnana that cites 'Nonlinear Potential Theory of Degenerate Elliptic Equations' of Heinonen. J, Kilpeläinen. T and Martio. O. I believe they are referencing chapter 16 of the latter, but I am not entirely sure whether $\mathfrak h$-harmonic functions are the same as $p$-harmonic functions. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Any reference or explanations is appreciated.

The strong maximum principle for $p$-harmonic functions is given in, for example, Corollary 2.21 in Notes on the $p$-Laplace equation by Peter Lindqvist.
